# Last track does not show in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, gpx

I have a GPX file and it has several tracks in it. When I drag it to Google Earth the last track shows up for a few seconds until the slider animation completes then it disappears. The slider shows 12/16/2016 12PM to 01/05/2015 3PM.

My last track looks like this:

```
<trk>
 <name>Route 2</name>
 <desc>Route 2</desc>
 <trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="43.452919" lon="-83.759766">
    <ele>0</ele>
    <time>2016-01-05T20:57:07.151Z</time>
    <desc>Route 2</desc>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="49.353756" lon="-77.563477">
    <ele>0</ele>
    <time>2016-01-05T20:57:07.152Z</time>
    <desc>Route 2</desc>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="49.610710" lon="-69.433594">
    <ele>0</ele>
    <time>2016-01-05T20:57:07.153Z</time>
    <desc>Route 2</desc>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="46.255847" lon="-83.671875">
    <ele>0</ele>
    <time>2016-01-05T20:57:07.154Z</time>
    <desc>Route 2</desc>
  </trkpt>
 </trkseg>
</trk>
```

This is a route I hand created. I change the time stamp by 1 millisecond for each point in order to have the track know what direction it is going in.

If I do the same points in a KML doc then they appear fine on Google Earth.

If I add an item that has a later time stamp then my route does appear -- so it seems like whatever is the latest time stamped track fails to show.

```
<wpt lat="48.195387" lon="-73.828125">
 <time>2016-01-05T21:00:00.000</time>
 <name>Waypoint 10</name>
 <desc />
</wpt>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Earth operates based on the time slider. So maybe by using these artificial very small increments, you create a problem. Try using more real-world time stamps, such as incrementing them by a second or a minute.